# Inconsistency in favourites bar icons behaviour after application launch in GNOME desktop

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, favorites

I have several of my favourite apps as icons on my desktop favouries bar but they can behave differently.  Some of them (e.g. Firefox, Thunderbird, Geany) just add a dot to the icon each time you instance them whilst others (e.g. Dolphin, Netbeans) add another icon to the bar.  Is there a way to set this behaviour? I prefer the multiple dot approach.

Secondly, is there a way to change an app's icon?  For instance, Dolphin and the default file manager use the same icon - just wondered if I could distinguish more easily between them.